# How to extract item by item from list and perform a new function on it

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to perform a new function on each item from **posts_list = []**
let's say i have this function

```
def hello():
    print('Hello post from posts_list')
```

and i want to give it to each item on **posts_list = []**

```
titles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='item__ad--title']")
posts_list = []
def xxx():
    for title in titles:
        x = title.get_attribute('href')
        posts_list.append(x)

        for p in posts_list:
            print(f"this is {p}")
    print(len(posts_list))

    xxx()
```

Comment: You want to call `hello()` inside the loop of `posts_list`, and you want to pass the `p` to `hello()` right?

Comment: yes that's what i want

Comment: Check out the answer @Ihab Hamed, and let me know how this goes for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this is what you're looking for?

```
def xxx():
    for title in titles:
        x = title.get_attribute('href')
        posts_list.append(x)
    
    # this should come out of the titles loop, 
    # since you were currently adding data, 
    # and then you can traverse through it 
    for p in posts_list:
       # Calling your help(), assuming it does accepts p from your list
       help(p)
    print(len(posts_list))

# Indentation matters, please look into the Python Indentation, 
# this is where you will be calling your method outside your def xxx()
xxx()
```

Your help function:

```
# def help should accept an argument p, which you will use to print the data
def help(p):
  print(f"this is {p}")
```

Please look into [Python Indentation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/indentation-in-python/#:%7E:text=Python%20indentation%20is%20a%20way,a%20particular%20block%20of%20code.&text=Python%20uses%20indentation%20to%20highlight,the%20same%20block%20of%20code.) to brush up your Python basics, because it does matter when you write code.

Answer (score 1):

The indentation in the original post is badly skewed.

The problem that you are trying to solve is best approached with list comprehension:

```
posts_list = [title.get_attribute('href') for title in titles]
[help(p) for p in posts_list]
```

If you are not interested in the posts as such but only in the results of applying `help` to them, the two loops can be combined:

```
[help(title.get_attribute('href')) for title in titles]
```